# What notation for derivatives should be used?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I‘ve seen Leibniz’s, Lagrange’s, Euler’s and Newton’s notation for derivatives. They’re quite different, and I suppose they all have different applications where they shine the brightest.

In what circumstances are the different notations most common? Is there a reason to have multiple notations for the same thing?

Comment: If your goal is that people understand you, you should use the notation which simplifies life most for the expected readership. In most cases, this means that it is best to use the notation everybody else around you uses...

Comment: Often it is nice to use the more concise derivative notations for inline formulas. For example, $\partial_x f$ looks better (to me) than $\partial f/\partial x$. So in some cases notation may also be chosen out of convenience more than anything else.

Comment: All notations defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a concept is as important as the derivative is, and with as complex a history, and used in as many niche applications, it is prone to having many different notations that are used within different circles. The short answer is, **whatever area you're working in, see what notation textbooks/professors/papers in the field typically use. If everyone in your field uses the same notation, use that one.**

Here are a few loose guidelines from my experience:

- The notation $\dot y$ is typically used to mean the derivative with respect to time. It is very common in classical mechanics.
- The notation $dy/dx$ is *typically* used more in applied math and the notation $f'(x)$ is *typically* used more in pure math. This one is very rough and should be taken with a large dose of salt.
- The partial derivative notation $\partial f/\partial x$ is the "default" and the most common. It is also the most classical.
- In partial differential equations, the notation $f_x$ for the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ is very common.
- I think mathematicians working with differential forms seem to like $D_x f$ for the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$. Many feel that $\partial f/\partial x$ is just too clunky, especially when written in matrices.

Sometimes other notations will appear. Once, in a very specific area I was working in, the notation was $\delta y/\delta t$!

Comment: You also see $\dot{y}$ for $1$-dimensional evolution, such as arc length with respect to an arbitrary affine parameter.

Comment: Did they use $\delta$ because they didn’t know how to typeset $\partial$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin [No!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative)

Comment: @J.G. New to me.

Comment: @J.G. interesting, I had no idea where the notation came from (I don't even know what a functional is!), but that seems like the origin of it: $\delta t$ was supposed to be a small timestep in a simulation.

Comment: @Math2718 It's been a bit roundabout because $\delta t$ started as a small change in $t$, so $\delta f/\delta t$, as ratio of two numbers, is the gradient of a [secant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_line), and we recover $df/dt$ in the $\delta t\to0$ limit as the gradient of a [tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent). And then two more kinds of derivative, $\partial f/\partial t$ and $\delta f/\delta t$, followed as needed.

Comment: I think $\partial f \over \partial x$ should be on  your list as the traditional version of $D_xf$..

Comment: @RobArthan added.